# Describe the function of a salt bridge, What would happen if the half-cell compartments of a galvanic cell were not connected?

Tags: electrochemistry

I know,  The primary function of a salt bridge is to complete the circuit, so that charge can flow from one half-cell to the other. The second function is to balance the mass by allowing the anions to move to the half-cell where addition cations are being produced.But I can't seem to figure out what would happen if the half-cell compartments of a galvanic cell weren't connected?

Answer (score 2):

My electrochemical knowledge is a wee bit rusty, but I believe the salt bridge helps balance the **charges** and not mass.

What charge you ask? So, let imagine you start up your galvanic cell (below). Electrons from the Zn move to Cu electrode. You start to build up a negative charge on the Cu which would resist/repel further addition of electrons after a period of time, hence production of electricity ceases.

By having a salt bridge, the electrolyte ions can move from one side to the other to mitigate this issue.

[image: Galvanic cell]